# Unable to delete row from table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: ssms

I highlighted a row in my table, and pressed right-click >> delete.

My error message is as follows:

> No rows were deleted.
>
> A problem occurred attempting to delete row 1.
>   Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
>
> Error Message: The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list.  The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
>
> Correct the errors and attempt to delete the row again or press ESC to cancel the change(s).
>   [OK]

The show SQL pane reveals the following:

```
    SELECT     TOP (200) ReceiptID, fkSID, fkStudyID, Amount, Paymentdt, Purpose, dtCreated, CreatedBy, dtChanged, ChangedBy, MedicalExam, NPT, LP, MRI, Food, Transportation, 
                      TransportationDetail, Other, OtherSpecify, FR, TR, OtR, fkLocationID, Notes, CashAmountOut, CashOutby, CashOutApprovedby, Cashoutdt, CashAmountReturned, 
                      CashReturnedby, CashReturnReceivedby, CashReturnReceiveddt, AllDocumentationComplete, ReceiptStatus, AddCashRequests, fkBatchSubmissionsID, Parking, 
                      ParkingStickerID, Other2, OtherSpecify2
FROM         tblReceipts
ORDER BY ReceiptID DESC
```

I do not know how to correct the errors.  Does anyone know what to do in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unable to delete but what do you mean to your Query?

Comment: you have more items in your `select` than items in `insert` statement..

Comment: reds - My goal is to delete row 1, but I have only interacted with the data through the SSMS GUI.  I am not an experienced user, and do not know what the Query is, nor whether I want to do anything to it.

Comment: Smart - I do not know where to find the INSERT statement.  I included the code that came up upon pressing the "show SQL" button (as it included the word "SELECT"), but maybe this was wrong?  What INSERT statement is triggered when I press the delete key?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete Table Content do it like this:

> Delete from your table where ReceiptID < 201

If you want to delete 1 - 200 record